# Marginilizing in multivariate Statistical Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning, normal-distribution, expectation

Suppose we draw $X = [x_1,...,x_i,...x_r,...,x_t...,x_j,...x_N]$ from $N(0,\Sigma)$. is there any way to compute $E[x_ix_j]$ and how about  $E[x_ix_jx_rx_t]$ ?

How can I compute the marginal probability $P(x_i,x_j)$?

I studied some information about this topic here: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html

in the link when divide a vector $X=[x_1,x_2] \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ in to two parts we have $
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \Sigma_{11}&\Sigma_{12}\\
    \Sigma_{21}&\Sigma_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 
    \mu{1}\\
    \mu{2}\\
\end{bmatrix}$
and can create $P(x_1)$ by $P(x_1)=\int P(x_1,x_2)dx_2$.

but i did not get good views when the elements of $X$ is more than two. it is so difficult to compute $N-2$ integrals to compute $P(x_i,x_j)$ and then we can compute $E[x_ix_j]$. is there any simpler way to compute it?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$ E[X_iX_j] = Cov[X_i, X_j] + E[X_i]E[X_j] = Cov[X_i, X_j] $$

as $E[X_i] = E[X_j] = 0$. So you just need to read the $(i, j)$ element in the covariance matrix as your desired answer.

Also, the random vector $(X_i, X_j)$ is an affine transformation of the multivariate normal random vector $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. Therefore it also follows a bivariate normal distribution, and thus you just need to extract the mean and covariance matrix of $(X_i, X_j)$ to completely characterize its distribution. Again this can be directly read from the given mean vector and covariance matrix of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.

Comment: thank you so much, i find it just before your answer ,but now i have another question, how about when we want to compute $E[x_ix_jx_tx_r]$?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Higher_moments

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem